# How to find the formula for exponential growth in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

[I am working on this. Can anyone please help me?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ67o.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exponential growth in excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1317258/exponential-growth-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a typical compounding approach.

1. place 100 in **A1**
2. place an estimated monthly rate in **B1**
3. In **A2** enter:

   =A1*(1+B$1)

and copy downward:

[image]

Comment: Ciao, cow.  Hint: you have to use the *monthly* interest rate. Yours is =.05/12.  Fill the formula down to row 60.  That's 5 years.

Comment: Actually you are both wrong. The monthly compounding rate for a 5% annual compounding rate is NOT 5%/12. Instead, it's the solution to the following equation: (1+x%)^12 = 105%.

Comment: @ttarchala you are correct, the value I use was only a rough approximation