# Exponential growth in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

What kind of formula should I type in order to get these values? I know that this is exponential growth and growth rate is 0.42. I appreciate if someone can help me with this. [Please see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPw2Q.png)

Comment: Same question. Same OP.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What research have you done so far? What have you tried? Which bit about the formula is causing you problems? :)

Answer (score -1):

In Excel POWER function can be used to calculate the Exponentiate of any Cell/Number.

I can suggest you one sample Formula:
`=Power(A1,2)` or `=A1^2`

*Exponential growth can be found in excel in two ways and are basically for Forecasting.*

1. Linear Growth 2. Curve Growth.

For the liner growth you can use the Growth Function.

The Syntax is `=Growrth(known_y's, known_x's, new_x's`)

**Check the Screen Shot below I've shown Example for both:**

[image]

**N.B.** *Since in the attached Sheet you have not show what Formula is been used but my experience says, seems there the POWER function has been used.*

Comment: The question is not about estimating the growth rate, the growth rate is specified.